# Can i disable 'Debug Build' without re-compiling PHP?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I need to disable 'Debug Build' mode in my installation of PHP. Is this possible without re-compiling PHP? (Note I am not the original server admin). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--enable-debug` is a compile-time option. If your PHP was compiled as a debug build, it will always be a debug build and no runtime configuration can change that.

In short, yes, you have to throw it away. But you really should not compile PHP yourself; this is a maintenance nightmare. Especially when Linux distributions do it for you for free. Take this opportunity to get your system back onto a currently supported release build of PHP built for your Linux distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.